# How to handle multiple push notifications in android using GCM on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-2.0.0

When a push notifications is arrived, if user is not available to see the notification.  he got another notification the previsous is getting updated with the new one. 
But it should not update with latest one. we need to display each notification separately is that possible using GCM?

I have used Phonegap to develop the application

Comment: Are you using phonegap PushPlugin, or do you have your own BroadcastReceiver/IntentService to handle the arriving GCM messages?

Comment: PushPlugin has been used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look at the implementation of [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java), you'll see that they use a constant notification ID:

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 237;
...
mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

This would cause every new notification to overwrite the existing one. That's why only the last notification is displayed.

If you want to change the behavior, you have to change the code to use a unique notification ID for each notification.

Answer (score 5):

The PushPlugin supports sending notification Ids in the payload.
When sendingthe GCM message from your server, include a unique `data.notId` along with `data.message` and `data.title`, and you will have separate notifications.

Comment: I followed by your words but last id which is suppose 12 then it is overriding second last but it should pass 11. so is there solution for this?

Comment: The trick to getting `data.notId` to work is to use a unique _integer_. The plugin will be using Integer.parseInt to evaluate `notId`, so longs, floats, and non-numeric strings will fail. You'll see `Number format exception - Error parsing notId` in your logcat output when you're getting it wrong.