# To receive multiple push notifications of different criteria and update the notification based on that

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have incorporated GCM notification, but it overwrites the existing, then by suggestion given in

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163399/how-to-handle-multiple-push-notifications-in-android-using-gcm-on-phonegap) i used and got it, but it is updating as multiple notifications, need to achieve like this image -

[image]

Here i was unable to achieve this type in multiple lines.  I am trying with [BigNotify](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify) not with styles and expand but i need to stack the notification as declared in [Summarize notification guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

To the least case I am trying to achieve that 5 messages from 3 chats as summarizing the notification, any work around on this ?

Comment: expanded digest layout or inboxStyle code snippet will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up customizing it to achieve it by this code.

```
int notificationId =  Prefs.getIntPref(context, Prefs.NEWLEAD_NOTIFY, 0);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message",message);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        array_messages.add(message);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setTicker("My product")
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("My product")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE) ;

        if(array_messages.size()==1)
            builder.setContentText(message);
        else
            builder.setContentText(array_messages.size() +" Lead notifications");


        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        if(array_messages.size()<=5) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array_messages.size(); i++) {

                inboxStyle.addLine(array_messages.get(i));
            }
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("My Product");
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText(array_messages.size() +" Lead notifications");
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

                inboxStyle.addLine(array_messages.get(i));
            }

            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("My product");
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText(array_messages.size() +" Lead notifications");
        }
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        notificationId = notificationId + 1;

        Prefs.setIntPref(context, Prefs.NEWLEAD_NOTIFY, notificationId);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer, tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390803/android-notification-inboxstyle-still-shows-default-notification-layout)

`

```
public static void pushNotification(Activity currentActivity, String title, String content[]){

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.getBaseContext(), FileSharingActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(currentActivity);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(FileSharingActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    nm.notify(nextId++, new Notification.InboxStyle(new Notification.Builder(currentActivity.getBaseContext())
            .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("Content title")
            .setContentText("Content text")
            .setNumber(4)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent))
            .addLine("First Message")
            .addLine("Second Message")
            .addLine("Third Message")
            .addLine("Fourth Message")
            .setBigContentTitle("Here Your Messages")
            .setSummaryText("+3 more")
            .build());
}
```

`